WAIT_AT_LOW_PRIORITY doesn work for shrink data file
When I try to make shrink data file like this:
DBCC SHRINKFILE (N'DataFileName' , 1500) WITH WAIT_AT_LOW_PRIORITY
I get the error:
'WAIT_AT_LOW_PRIORITY' is not a recognized option.
What can be the reason?

It's well documented that you'll need to be on SQL Server 2022+/MI/SQLDB in order for this option to be available.

WAIT_AT_LOW_PRIORITY with shrink operations Applies to: SQL Server
2022 (16.x) and later versions, Azure SQL Database, Azure SQL Managed
Instance

Attempting to do so on any lower version will result in a language error.
